# How to manipulate a PHP Array in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an Array in PHP which contains data from database. And it prints out also as a table in the same page which has an AJAX delete function.

### Trying to explain better

The array contains debt sums related to many people, it is the application's main function. In the same page, there is a table containing every debt record related to the array, which can be deleted or edited using AJAX.

I have coded the part of deleting the record and removing the TR entry, but it's not enough: **I'd like to change also the debt sum using AJAX which is an PHP Array**.

### What I have

I have the JS function which removes the TR when the delete button is clicked

```
// TR Fading when deleted
    $('.delete')
        .click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'history/delete/id/'+$(this).attr('id')
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
        return false;
        });
```

and I have the PHP array [(image)](http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4250500/4250728_f8d1.png)

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what you're trying to accomplish? I sure don't.

Comment: Just a note: You shouldn't use GET to alter (remove in your case) data. Use POST or DELETE.

Comment: I just would like to modify my array's value index when clicked in the delete button so that my array can still have the correct debt sums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest returning the PHP array in JSON format.  So the output from your script might look something like:

```
[
    {'debtor': 'Bixo', 'creditor': 'Paulo', 'value': 42.98},
    {'debtor': 'Bixo', 'creditor': 'Otavio', 'value': 12.28},
    {'debtor': 'Luis', 'creditor': 'Bixo', 'value': 10.76},
    {'debtor': 'Luis', 'creditor': 'Paulo', 'value': 248.18},
    {'debtor': 'Luis', 'creditor': 'Otavio', 'value': 49.28},
    {'debtor': 'Otavio', 'creditor': 'Paulo', 'value': 122.89}
]
```

If you return that with the JSON content type, then many JS libraries (it looks like you're using jQuery?) will automatically parse that into an object - an array of objects in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too vague to give a good answer, but have a look at PHP's [`json_encode`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) functions. These allow you to encode a PHP variable in JSON, which can then be parsed readily by JavaScript and manipulated as a normal JavaScript object. When you've made the changes you want, you can then send it back to PHP via AJAX.